# Boost.Proto and Complex Transform

Tags: c++, boost-proto

I'm experimenting with *Proto* to build a *DSEL* that operates on geometric vectors. I'm trying to write a transform that would take an assign expression and unroll it component wise. For instance, I want to replace

```
p = q + r;
```

by

```
p[0] = q[0] + r[0],
p[1] = q[1] + r[1],
...,
p[N] = q[N] + r[N],
p;
```

So far I have been able to *mostly* make it work by making a transform template `unroll_vector_expr` that recursively unrolls the expression for each vector component, in conjunction with a `distribute_subscript` transform.

I don't seem to understand whats the rationale for the 'parameters' used with `boost::result_of` and `result_of::make_expr`. The documentation, examples and internal code seem to mix `Expr`, `impl::expr` and `impl::expr_param`. I'm not sure what should I be using and when so that the `result_type` matches the actual result type. Currently I made it work by trial an error, by examining the error messages and fixing the `const` and `&` discrepancies. However, as soon as I deep copy the expression the terminals are no longer hold by reference and my code fails.

```
struct distribute_subscript
  : or_<
        scalar_grammar
      , when<
            vector_literal
          , _make_subscript( _, _state )
        >
      , plus< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , minus< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , multiplies< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , divides< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , assign< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
    >
{};

template< std::size_t I, std::size_t N >
struct unroll_vector_expr_c;

template< std::size_t I, std::size_t N >
struct unroll_vector_expr_c
  : transform< unroll_vector_expr_c< I, N > >
{
    template< typename Expr, typename State, typename Data >
    struct impl
      : transform_impl< Expr, State, Data >
    {
        typedef
            typename result_of::make_expr<
                tag::comma
              , typename boost::result_of<
                    distribute_subscript(
                        Expr
                      , typename result_of::make_expr<
                            tag::terminal
                          , boost::mpl::size_t< I - 1 >
                        >::type
                    )
                >::type
              , typename boost::result_of<
                    unroll_vector_expr_c< I + 1, N >(
                        Expr
                    )
                >::type
            >::type
            result_type;

        result_type operator ()(
            typename impl::expr_param expr
          , typename impl::state_param state
          , typename impl::data_param data
        ) const
        {
            return
                make_expr< tag::comma >(
                    distribute_subscript()(
                        expr
                      , make_expr< tag::terminal >( 
                            boost::mpl::size_t< I - 1 >()
                        )
                    )
                  , unroll_vector_expr_c< I + 1, N >() (
                        expr
                    )
                );
        }
    };
};

template< std::size_t N >
struct unroll_vector_expr_c< N, N >
  : transform< unroll_vector_expr_c< N, N > >
{
    template< typename Expr, typename State, typename Data >
    struct impl
      : transform_impl< Expr, State, Data >
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::result_of<
                distribute_subscript(
                    Expr
                  , typename result_of::make_expr<
                        tag::terminal
                      , boost::mpl::size_t< N - 1 >
                    >::type
                )
            >::type
            result_type;

        result_type operator ()(
            typename impl::expr_param expr
          , typename impl::state_param state
          , typename impl::data_param data
        ) const
        {
            return
                distribute_subscript()(
                    expr
                  , make_expr< tag::terminal >( 
                        boost::mpl::size_t< N - 1 >()
                    )
                );
        }
    };
};

struct unroll_vector_expr
  : transform< unroll_vector_expr >
{
    template< typename Expr, typename State, typename Data >
    struct impl
      : transform_impl< Expr, State, Data >
    {
        typedef
            typename dimension<
                typename boost::remove_reference<
                    typename boost::result_of<
                        _value( State )
                    >::type
                >::type
            >::type
            dimension;

        typedef
            typename result_of::make_expr<
                tag::comma
              , typename boost::result_of<
                    unroll_vector_expr_c< 1, dimension::value >(
                        Expr
                    )
                >::type
              , State
            >::type
            result_type;

        result_type operator ()(
            typename impl::expr_param expr
          , typename impl::state_param state
          , typename impl::data_param data
        ) const
        {
            return
                make_expr< tag::comma >(
                    unroll_vector_expr_c< 1, dimension::value >()(
                        expr
                    )
                  , boost::ref( state )
                );
        }
    };
};
```

How should I write my transform so that the `result_type` matches the result from `operator ()`, and works for `terminal`s both hold by value and by reference?

**Update**: Code updated after *Eric*'s answer. The only remaining mismatch between `result_type` and `make_expr` is for the *first* instantiation of `unroll_vector_expr_c`, where the `terminal< mpl::size_t< 0 > >::type` is held by *const reference* instead of by *value*. Curiously enough, subsequent instantiations of the same template with higher indices do not result in this issue.

**Update**: I managed to get the code to fully work, after modifying the `distribue_subscript` transform to force to take the subscript index by value:

```
struct distribute_subscript
  : or_<
        scalar_grammar
      , when<
            vector_literal
          , _make_subscript( _, _byval( _state ) ) // <-- HERE
        >
      , plus< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , minus< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , multiplies< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , divides< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
      , assign< distribute_subscript, distribute_subscript >
    >
{};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick answer for now. I'll try to look more closely at your transform tomorrow.

The meaning of `impl::expr` and `impl::expr_param` can be understood by looking at documentation for [`transform_impl`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/proto/transform_impl.html). In short, use `impl::expr_param` in the signature of your transform's `operator()`, since it adds a `const &` to ensure that expressions don't get copied when passed to your function. Use `Expr` in your type computations, like in `boost::result_of`. `impl::expr` isn't useful for much and can be ignored.

As for `deep_copy` always forcing your terminals to be held by value, that's pretty much what `deep_copy` is for. But maybe you mean something else, since I don't see `deep_copy` in your code anywhere.

A word about `make_expr`: it forces you to think *very carefully* about which nodes should be stored by reference and which by value. In the type computation (`result_of::make_expr`), reference types are things that should be held by reference, but in the actual function call (`proto::make_expr`), you must wrap things with `boost::ref` if you want then held by reference. This is weird. Check the user docs for [`make_expr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.front_end.making_lazy_functions.lazy_functions_made_simple_with__literal_make_expr____literal_).

Comment: I mention `deep_copy` because using it causes my `result_type` and actual result from `make_expr` to be different. The point about using `boost::ref` is exactly what I was missing about `make_expr`, I only want the original terminal to be kept by reference (the one hold in `state`).

Comment: Thank you Eric, I have finally been able to make this work! Would you care to comment on why my last fix was needed? Whenever you have time, of course.

Comment: `_make_subscript` is a typedef for `proto::functional::make_expr<proto::tag::subscript>`. Like `proto::result_of::make_expr`, it is sensitive to whether its arguments are references or not. So if you want to store a child by value with `_make_subscript`, you have to make sure it's not a reference. You might be thinking, "But I passed an rvalue to the `distribute_subscript` transform. Why does Proto think it's an lvalue?" In C++03, there's no way to overload a function on the rvalue-ness of its arguments. So `distribute_subscript::operator()` deduces its "state" parameter to be a `const &`. HTH